# How can I prevent forgetting to collect a kotlin flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have an application that uses flows that sometimes return nothing but they have side-effects. A common mistake that I make is to forget to collect the flow.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow

fun createFlowWithSideEffects() = flow<Unit> {
    println("Side-effect")
}

fun main() {
    createFlowWithSideEffects()
    // as flow is never collected the side-effect will never happen
}
```

Is there a good pattern to follow to prevent, or perhaps a linter than can warn about, uncollected flows?

Comment: Common mistake you make is to have flows with side-effects in the first place. Why do you need this? Flows are for acquiring some kind of the data, not for performing actions underneath.

Comment: You can maybe craft a rule applied by a static code analyzer to check that any created flow is collected. But more details about your use-case might help to provide a relevant answer.

Comment: I am using a messaging system with an API that looks like:
`fun <T, R> send(message: T): Flow<R>`
Depending on the type of message that was sent sometimes the response is a flow of data that you care about. Sometimes you don't care about the response.
The system is setup such that if you don't collect the flow, the message doesn't get sent. I can't change the way this messaging system works.

Comment: Ok, this API is definitely wrong. Maybe you could wrap it in your own utility which would ensure all requests are sent? If you can't do anything about it, then I guess your best bet is to write a plugin for compiler or some linter.